# Does php script executed by user count as alive session?

Tags: linux, php, sshd

Let's say I set in sshd_config ClientAliveInterval 900. Will the system disconnect me if I run some script for 16 minutes?

Comment: [What options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` in sshd_config exactly do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-exac)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with different systems the sending of null packets (equivalent to a SSH Keep-Alive) will prevent you from being disconnected. This is done by the client (e.g. PuTTY) if the server supports it.

If you have the ClientAliveInterval set on the server, it will most likely not impact your remote connection to this machine (See Seth's linked answer for details). You should set it on the connecting machine.

The Server might however be disconnecting you anyways after a certain amount of time if it is set to kill sessions longer than a given time. We had one server on a hard limit of 8 hours per session. This was however enforced by another program.

The process running on the window/session has no impact on the idle time disconnect.